# How to dismount a VHD that has been absorbed into a Storage Space

Tags: windows-server-2012, vhd, diskmanagement, storage-spaces, vhdx

Normally in Windows, you can create a Virtual Hard Disk (VHD), see it in the Disk Management, right-click, and remove it:

[image]

No problem.

### Storage Spaces Hides Disks

I want to test the resiliency of Storage Spaces, and the ability to migrate them between servers. Once a disk has been added to a *Storage Pool*, it no longer appears in **Disk Management**. I need to surprise remove a VHD from the server, but there's no UI option to do it.

If i were using a physical disk, it would be trivial to disconnect the drive from the computer (thus ensuring that Storage Spaces doesn't expect it, and has no chance to rebalance beforehand):

[image]

### How to unplug a vhd?

But once a disk is added to a storage pool, there is no longer any UI options for that disk. I don't want to use the Storage Spaces UI to *Remove a physical disk* from the pool:

[image]

Because:

- storage spaces will migrate data from that disk onto other disks in the pool (defeating the point of a surprise removal)
- storage spaces will migrate data from that disk onto other disks in the pool (defeating the point of the test of migrating disks to another server)

[image]

### I need the surprise removal

In the same way i can unplug a physical hard disk, how do i unplug a virtual hard disk?

Microsoft has the exact PowerShell commandlet to [disconnect a vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848562.aspx):

> ### Dismount-VHD
>
> Dismounts a virtual hard disk.
>
> PS C:> Dismount-VHD –Path c:\test\testvhdx.vhdx

Unfortunately it doesn't work - for the same reason. The VHD is *"gone"*, *"invisible"*, absorbed into the Storage Pool, gone from any ability to interact with it:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Dismount-VHD –Path D:\VirtualMachines\StorageSpaceTest\StorageSpaceTest1.vhdx
Dismount-VHD : Windows cannot dismount the disk because it is not mounted.
At line:1 char:1
+ Dismount-VHD –Path D:\VirtualMachines\StorageSpaceTest\StorageSpaceTest1.vhdx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Vhd.P...mountVhdCommand:DismountVhdCommand) [Dismount-VHD], VirtualizationOperationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.DismountVhdCommand
```

It seems once a VHD has been added to a storage pool, it cannot be dismounted.

How do i dismount a VHD that has been added to a storage pool?

### DiskPart

The command line tool **diskpart** has a [command to detach a virtual disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/detach-vdisk):

```
DISKPART> select vdisk file="F:\Foo\Contoso37.vhd"

DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> detach vdisk

Virtual Disk Service error:
The virtual disk is already detached.
```

But it fails for the same reason, the `.vhdx` has already been "detached" when it went into the StoragePool.

### Bonus Chatter

The current VHDX files are sitting in `D:\...`, which itself is a Parity Space. I cannot simply turn off the PC and simply rename the files. Not only is turning off the server not a viable option right now, it defeats the point of the test: having Storage Spaces react while it is running

**Edit**: Same thing happens in Windows Server 2016